# One OSGi Bundle Loading CamelContext From Another Bundle

Tags: osgi, spring-dm

I have several OSGi bundles (say A, B and C).  Each of these bundles has its own Camel routes defined using Spring DM XML file.

I'd like to monitor each route by adding a wiretap at the beginning of each route.   For example, the wiretaps would send data to a route defined in a different bundle (say Z)

```
...
<wiretap uri="direct-vm:data-gathering-route/>
...
```

In bundle Z, I would define the said route in a file named `camelContext.xml`.  Its location is `META-INF/spring`, as follows:

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct-vm:data-gathering-route"/>
...
  </route>
```

The reason for defining this route in a separate bundle is because I don't want to repeat this in bundles A, B and C.  So I hope I could import this route definition (within bundles A, B and C Camel Context files) using the Spring DM import statement, as follows:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/camelContext.xml"/>
```

When I deployed bundles A, B, C and Z in Karaf, it complains that it can't find the `camelContext.xml` file.

Am I approaching this the right way?

Thanks.